# Solidworks Windows installation damaging GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

A couple of years back, I used to run Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 in a dual boot scenario where windows and ubuntu were installed on different drives.  However, when installing Solidworks 2018 in a network license configuration into Windows, the GRUB no longer shows up and I cannot boot either operating system.  At the time, I found somewhere on the internet that some Windows software programs write licensing info to the same area where GRUB is installed and corrupts the GRUB files.  Ultimately I narrowed it down to Solidworks as causing the issue, but wasn't able to find a good solution to keep my GRUB from getting damaged when installing Solidworks. I tried different methods of repairing GRUB, but I was not able to get Solidworks to install and run in Windows without damaging GRUB.

I am planning on returning to dual booting my computer with Ubuntu again in the next couple weeks and would appreciate any suggestions that you may have regarding this issue. I am a relatively basic user of Ubuntu, so there may be an obvious solution that I may be missing.

Comment: So, you want to know how to repair GRUB so you can boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 once again? Is that your objective?

Comment: Many Windows applications used flexnet for secuity. That wrote code into sector 32, between MBR & first partition. Grub wrote core.img into the sectors after the MBR & they conflicted. Grub was updated not to use sector 32. But with new UEFI systems Windows has a system reserved partition for the security info. All systems since 2012 are required to be UEFI if Windows pre-installed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition

Comment: Oldfred - Thanks, yes it looks like the Solidworks license manager uses FLEXnet Publisher.  Do new installations of GRUB now not conflict with Flexnet?  I originally attempted this with Windows 10 and either Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 a year or two ago.  If not, is there a way to relocate where GRUB is located?

Comment: K7AAY - Yes, either that or set up Ubuntu and Grub in a way where the Flexnet portion of Soildworks doesn't conflict with grub and visa versa when I go to install Solidworks.  I'll be starting from scratch with new Windows and Ubuntu installations.  Thanks

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get Solidworks and its Flexnet components to run in Windows without damaging the GRUB?  Is there a way to assign GRUB to a different location during Ubuntu installation that is still safe to avoid it being overwritten?